# login to uploaded.net using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

i want to log in to uploaded.net using selenium in python. here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.uploaded.net/#login')

user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@name='id'][@value='Account-ID']")

user.clear()

user.send_keys("mypass")

password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@name='pw'][@value='Password']").click()

password.send_keys('mypass')
```

the problem is that, selenium successfully fill username field, but can not fill password field. i am sure selenium find password field correctly, but send_key function fail to fill password field.

does anyone know how to solve problem?

Comment: Are you sure that password type is text, not password? `find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@name='pw'][@value='Password']")`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I checked uplaoded.net and it looks that input type is *password* (obviously), not *text* as you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@name='pw'][@value='Password']").click()
```

Once you click the element, the type changes to 'password' and therefore selenium can't send commands to an the element that you saved in password. This is sometimes called a 'stale' element because it doesn't exist on the page anymore.

You can fix this by changing your code to this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@name='pw'][@value='Password']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password'][@name='pw'][@value='Password']").send_keys('mypass')
```